# images go on top of text when changing size of browser

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgPuu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5G05.png)

Hello i am still beginner in designing websites and I  have small problem idk the solution for it , i would appreciate someone helping me out with this please , there are two pictures , one picture where the cloud is overlapped ontop of texts this is when the browser size is smaller , but the other one looks normal when the browser size is maximized , what i want to know is there any way to make the image go under the text just like normal other websites

this is the css code for both images

```
.top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 400px;
}

<div class="div1">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="">
    <h1>Albsrawy</h1>
    <h2>Discord programmer</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt=""> <br>
    <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the corresponding HTML to it? Why use absoltue positiong in pixels which will have 0 responsivness? what have you tried so far?

Comment: hello i added the html too , which type of positioning and which unit for absolute positioning , for example if i want to change its position and make it responsive on all screens , what do u advice ? :)

Comment: if you have to do absolute positioning, work with relative units as percentages or vw/vh. With the code provided, I cant reproduce the issue you describing. To much of the code is either missing or not linked (like the complete image part, background images... However, the easiest way to "solve" the issue would be to add a positiv z-index to h1 and h2

Comment: thank u so much i will do that <3 , and please i have small question if u don't mind , since i am new to web developing , the most common way to position elements would be using relative positioning what shall i use just commonly ? :O

Comment: always come down on what you try to achieve. there is nothing particuluar wrong with usign relative and absolute positioning. However in most cases you should use relative units (%, vh, vw) instead of definite units (px, em, rem).  In your case you might even be betetr off using multiple background images...

Comment: aha thats great to know , really thank you so much for the help <3

Answer (score 0):

On your H1 tag, you could set the z-index to be higher than the cloud's

```
    .top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 400px;
}

<div class="div1">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="">
    <h1 style="z-index: 10;">Albsrawy</h1>
    <h2>Discord programmer</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt=""> <br>
<img src="images/mountain.png" alt="">
</div>
```